# Difficulty in changing old email to new email in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having a difficulty to change the current user's email to a new email which is user input and the email's validation. EDITED
Here's my controller

```
 public function changeuser(Request $request){
  $id = Auth::user()->id;
  $change_user = User::find($id);

  $valid = validator($request->only('oldpass', 'newpass', 'confirmpass'), [
  'olduser' => 'required|email|max:255|exists:users',
  'newuser' => 'required|email|max:255|different:olduser'
   ], [
    'newuser.required_with' => 'Choose different email.'
 ]);

  if ($valid->fails()) {
      return redirect('/manageaccount')->with('message','Failed to update email');
      }

  $change_user->email = $request->input('newuser');
  $change_user->save();

  return redirect('/manageaccount')->with('message', 'email changed successfully');

}
```

my blade.php which is in modal

```
<div class="thirdea" id="thirdea">

             <label><p class="small Montserrat">Enter Old Username</p></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control small Montserrat" name="olduser" value="" id="olduser">

            <label><p class="small Montserrat"> New Username</p></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control small Montserrat" name="newuser" value="" id="newuser">

        </div>
```

my route

```
Route::post('/changeuser/','UserController@changeuser');
```

Comment: Your modal doesn't have any field named `newuser`. Also the modal asks user to enter new password, not email.

Comment: There is no newuser input in your blade from which you trying to catch email in controller.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I posted the wrong modal and now, I edited the post.

Comment: Did you check your request if you get value for newuser or not ?

Comment: Changing the old email is working now but the email's validation if user put the wrong email format or if the old email was input in new email is the problem now.

Comment: There is no need for two fields olduser and newuser. You can update username by using single field and can check if it is alredy exist or not in database by using 'required|unique:users,email,'.$user->id.

Comment: can you tell the purpose of two fields olduser and newuser?

Comment: Olduser is for user's first email he/she put when he/she register and newuser is for new email

Comment: Fixing the really bad naming of fields and functions would probably reveal the mistake(s). It is absolutely unclear what your code is doing and supposed to do.

Comment: my code above is working just fine, it save the user's input but i need the validation, if the user input the same email or invalid email format.

Comment: Why the user have to insert the old email. Just use one field where the user can type his new email. In validation check if the email is unique in DB.

Answer (score 0):

In case of update user you can try validations for email like this :

```
 $validate = $request -> validate([
      'newuser' => 'required|unique:users,email,'.$user->id
 ]);
```

Comment: this is working, but i need the validation like it shows if the user input wrong email or if the user input again the email he/she used

Comment: yes using this code validation will fail if email was already in use.